# UDP traceroute delay?

Tags: linux, networking, udp, tcpdump

We are seeing timeout packages when running traceroute command between two Linux systems on a private network. However, we do not see such symptoms using TCP or ICMP over traceroute. This is a private network with a direct connect cable, so no switch or router is in between.

Every time, if we ran below two commands within 1 ms, we could clearly see the timeout. However, TCP/ICMP have no issues.

Commands:

```
[root@sch024 opt]# traceroute -s 192.168.173.1 -r -F 192.168.173.2 1472
traceroute to 192.168.173.2 (192.168.173.2), 30 hops max, 1472 byte packets
 1  192.168.173.2 (192.168.173.2)  0.251 ms  0.228 ms  0.211 ms

[root@sch024 opt]# traceroute -s 192.168.173.1 -r -F 192.168.173.2 1472
traceroute to 192.168.173.2 (192.168.173.2), 30 hops max, 1472 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * 192.168.173.2 (192.168.173.2)  0.219 ms  0.203 ms
```

TCPdump output from send end: (5 s delay, when issue occurred)

```
11:31:25.921047 IP 192.168.173.1.46286 > 192.168.173.2.33437: UDP, length 1472
11:31:25.921072 IP 192.168.173.1.23033 > 192.168.173.2.33438: UDP, length 1472
11:31:25.921093 IP 192.168.173.1.34026 > 192.168.173.2.33439: UDP, length 1472
11:31:25.921115 IP 192.168.173.1.19438 > 192.168.173.2.33440: UDP, length 1472
11:31:25.921140 IP 192.168.173.1.13794 > 192.168.173.2.33441: UDP, length 1472
11:31:25.921162 IP 192.168.173.1.21963 > 192.168.173.2.33442: UDP, length 1472
11:31:25.921186 IP 192.168.173.1.63873 > 192.168.173.2.33443: UDP, length 1472
11:31:25.921208 IP 192.168.173.1.51599 > 192.168.173.2.33444: UDP, length 1472
11:31:25.921230 IP 192.168.173.1.48325 > 192.168.173.2.33445: UDP, length 1472
11:31:25.921253 IP 192.168.173.1.11303 > 192.168.173.2.33446: UDP, length 1472
11:31:25.921275 IP 192.168.173.1.18195 > 192.168.173.2.33447: UDP, length 1472
11:31:25.921298 IP 192.168.173.1.56580 > 192.168.173.2.33448: UDP, length 1472
11:31:25.921323 IP 192.168.173.1.9626 > 192.168.173.2.33449: UDP, length 1472
11:31:30.922509 IP 192.168.173.1.19061 > 192.168.173.2.33450: UDP, length 1472
11:31:30.922535 IP 192.168.173.1.29498 > 192.168.173.2.33451: UDP, length 1472
11:31:30.922555 IP 192.168.173.1.39393 > 192.168.173.2.33452: UDP, length 1472
11:31:30.922577 IP 192.168.173.1.24223 > 192.168.173.2.33453: UDP, length 1472
11:31:30.922596 IP 192.168.173.1.29305 > 192.168.173.2.33454: UDP, length 1472
11:31:30.922616 IP 192.168.173.1.45487 > 192.168.173.2.33455: UDP, length 1472
11:31:30.922635 IP 192.168.173.1.25939 > 192.168.173.2.33456: UDP, length 1472
11:31:30.922656 IP 192.168.173.1.50773 > 192.168.173.2.33457: UDP, length 1472
```

Similar tcpdump output from receiving end:

```
11:31:25.923657 IP 192.168.173.1.19438 > 192.168.173.2.33440: UDP, length 1472
11:31:25.923680 IP 192.168.173.1.13794 > 192.168.173.2.33441: UDP, length 1472
11:31:25.923703 IP 192.168.173.1.21963 > 192.168.173.2.33442: UDP, length 1472
11:31:25.923729 IP 192.168.173.1.63873 > 192.168.173.2.33443: UDP, length 1472
11:31:25.923747 IP 192.168.173.1.51599 > 192.168.173.2.33444: UDP, length 1472
11:31:25.923770 IP 192.168.173.1.48325 > 192.168.173.2.33445: UDP, length 1472
11:31:25.923793 IP 192.168.173.1.11303 > 192.168.173.2.33446: UDP, length 1472
11:31:25.923816 IP 192.168.173.1.18195 > 192.168.173.2.33447: UDP, length 1472
11:31:25.923841 IP 192.168.173.1.56580 > 192.168.173.2.33448: UDP, length 1472
11:31:25.923861 IP 192.168.173.1.9626 > 192.168.173.2.33449: UDP, length 1472
11:31:30.925070 IP 192.168.173.1.19061 > 192.168.173.2.33450: UDP, length 1472
11:31:30.925091 IP 192.168.173.2 > 192.168.173.1: ICMP 192.168.173.2 udp port 33450 unreachable, length 556
11:31:30.925095 IP 192.168.173.1.29498 > 192.168.173.2.33451: UDP, length 1472
11:31:30.925099 IP 192.168.173.2 > 192.168.173.1: ICMP 192.168.173.2 udp port 33451 unreachable, length 556
11:31:30.925102 IP 192.168.173.1.39393 > 192.168.173.2.33452: UDP, length 1472
11:31:30.925106 IP 192.168.173.2 > 192.168.173.1: ICMP 192.168.173.2 udp port 33452 unreachable, length 556
11:31:30.925127 IP 192.168.173.1.24223 > 192.168.173.2.33453: UDP, length 1472
11:31:30.925138 IP 192.168.173.2 > 192.168.173.1: ICMP 192.168.173.2 udp port 33453 unreachable, length 556
11:31:30.925142 IP 192.168.173.1.29305 > 192.168.173.2.33454: UDP, length 1472
```

Can someone help diagnose what the issue could be? We already tried:

- Swapping cables
- Swapping card.

Right now the port is on a standalone NIC card which no other ports are in use.
Increased below kernel parameters but still no luck

```
net.core.rmem_default = 8388608
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_default = 8388608
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
net.ipv4.ipfrag_high_thresh = 1310720
net.ipv4.udp_rmem_min = 16384
net.ipv4.udp_wmem_min = 16384
net.ipv4.udp_mem = 8388608 12582912 16777216
```

We were also thinking if we could change the traffic to TCP but the application won't allow us. Because of that, the performance is seriously impacted. Any advise and suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: My first guess would be to check iptables, to make sure UDP packets aren't being blocked. An easy test would be to turn it off, and then test. `/etc/init.d/iptables save # /etc/init.d/iptables stop `

Comment: sorry. forget to mention, iptables are disabled on both servers but still the same.